# Polymer 1.0: Where is a working example of <paper-tabs> to control content?

Tags: polymer, element, polymer-1.0

### Background

- [Here is the documentation for the `<paper-tabs>` element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs).
- [Here is an issue describing the lack of content in the demo examples](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/issues/58).
- [The demo examples](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs?view=demo:demo/index.html) illustrate tab ***headers*** but omit tab ***content***.

## Question

Can someone please point to an example showing how `<paper-tabs>` can be used to control the display of content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the docs of the [first link](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs):

> A common usage for paper-tabs is to use it along with iron-pages to switch between different views.

```
<paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
  <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
  <div>Page 1</div>
  <div>Page 2</div>
  <div>Page 3</div>
</iron-pages>
```

Comment: How can i show different views on selected different tabs ? Each time on selection i want a different view to be loaded without reloading the page.

Comment: And this is why you include code snippets in responses. Thank you @Ricky for making this documentation available in perpetuity as the new WebComponents site has even fewer examples than the old docs. :thumbs_up: